# how to find a pointer to class based on the parameter of class in STL?

Tags: c++, stl

I am creating a project , where i am storing pointer to object in vector(STL).
I want to perform operation based on particular parameter of class . but how to use it i am not getting???

```
void BankingSystem :: Account_info()
{
    // Account * mAccount = vobject.back();
    long int ACC_NUMBER;
    cout << "Enter AccountNumber : " <<endl;
    cin >> ACC_NUMBER;
    Account * mAccount = std::find(vobject.begin(),vobject.end(),ACC_NUMBER); //finding based on Account number u can use any parameter
    cout << mAccount->Acc_holder.firstName << endl;
    cout << mAccount->Acc_holder.aadharNo <<endl;
    delete mAccount;
}
```

Comment: `delete mAccount;` -- Why are you doing this?

Comment: Please include the `Account` class definition. Make a [mcve].

Comment: `find` does not return a pointer. It returns an iterator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::find` (and `std::find_if`) returns an iterator to the found element (or `vobject.end()` if it's not found).

You could change it like this:

```
void BankingSystem :: Account_info()
{
    long int ACC_NUMBER;
    cout << "Enter AccountNumber : " <<endl;
    cin >> ACC_NUMBER;

    auto mAccount = std::find_if(vobject.begin(), vobject.end(),
                                [&ACC_NUMBER](const Account* a) {
                                    // acc_number is maybe called something else in
                                    // your Account class.
                                    return a->acc_number == ACC_NUMBER;
                                });

    // check that you actually found something before printing and erasing:
    if(mAccount != vobject.end()) {
        auto AccountPtr = *mAccount;
        cout << AccountPtr->Acc_holder.firstName << endl;
        cout << AccountPtr->Acc_holder.aadharNo <<endl;
        vobject.erase(mAccount);    // not "delete mAccount;"
        delete AccountPtr;          // if it's actually is supposed to be deleted
    }
}
```

You should however most probably store `Account` and not `Account*` in your `vector`.